# Changing one specific lowercase letter to uppercase letter PHP

Tags: uppercase, lowercase, letter

I am kinda new with PHP and I would love some help with converting a lowercase letter to an uppercase letter in an php echo (for example i to I)

So I currently use this line to output the url of the website:

```
<?php echo  "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

How do I get PHP to change only 1 letter to an capital letter in that line?

For example: http://idea.org/ to http://Idea.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what the purpose of this is, it might just be easier to use `str_replace` to change the name.

```
<?php echo  "http://" . str_replace('idea', 'Idea', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

or you can `ucfirst` which will capitalize the first letter only. We should also use `strtolower`.

```
<?php echo  "http://" . ucfirst(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Comment: Haha don't worry! It's all in the fun of learning. Good luck!

Comment: I needed to convert an 'i' in a domain name to a capital 'I'. But thanks for giving me more options :D